# VB.NET get attribute of parent node in XML

Tags: xml, vb.net

Let's say I am iterating through the following XML:

```
<Account Info="1234">
  <Number>3333</Number>
</Account>
<Account Info="0007">
  <Number>4444</Number>
</Account>

Dim MyNodes As XmlNodeList = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Account")

For Each node As XmlNode In MyNodes
    'Get attribute of the current 'Info' node
Next
```

I need to somehow go back within the loop and get the parent node's attribute value.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XmlNode` has a [`ParentNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.parentnode(v=vs.110).aspx) property

**Example**

```
Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Account")
For Each node As XmlNode In nodes
    Dim parentNode As XmlNode = node.ParentNode
    If parentNode Is Nothing OrElse parentNode.Attributes Is Nothing Then
        Continue For
    End If
    Dim attribute As XmlAttribute = parentNode.Attributes.ItemOf("SomeAttribute")
    If attribute Is Nothing Then
        Continue For
    End If
    Console.WriteLine(attribute.Value)
Next
```

Comment: sweet, will give this a go

Comment: OK, looks like I didn't need to go to the Parent level.
Just needed this line:
    Dim attribute As XmlAttribute =     parentNode.Attributes.ItemOf("SomeAttribute")

Will mark your answer as correct, if you could kindly edit. Thanks